# Java Stack program that doesn't use in-built classes

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am trying to make a stack without using the inbuilt classes provided by `java.util`. I wrote this program, but it doesn't seem to work correctly, whenever I attempt the use the `stack.pop()` method it doesn't seem to actually delete the first element of the stack, but instead returns pop: 0, I think this implies that it didn't delete anything at all. 
The Stack class contains the logic of the stack i.e. Push, Pop, etc.

**EDIT:** I see I mixed up the push and pop, I have now changed these to push: top++ and pop: --top. However, now I'm receiving an ArrayOutOfBounds error.

**EDIT2:** Ok, here's the sequence I'm testing the program on.

1. Type in 1 to work with stacks.
2. Type in 1 again to try to push a number.
3. Introduce any number, say 5.
4. Type in 2 to try to pop a number but instead I receive an `ArrayOutOfBoundsError`

Code:

```
public class Stack {  
    int[] stack;
    int top;

    public Stack() {      
        stack = new int[10];
        top = 0;
    }

    public void push(int a) {
        stack[top++] = a;
    }

    public int pop() {
        return stack[--top];
    }
}

public class StacksAndQueues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int answ = 1;

        {
            while (answ != 0) {
                int operation = 1;
                System.out.println("Introduce 1 to work with Stacks, 2 to work with Queues or 0 to exit");
                answ = sc.nextInt();
                switch (answ) {
                    case 0: 
                        System.out.println("Goodbye");
                        break;                       

                    case 1: 
                        while (operation !=0) {
                            Stack stack = new Stack();
                            System.out.println("Introduce 1 to push a number, 2 to pop a number, 3 to display contents and 0 to go back");
                            operation = sc.nextInt();
                            switch (operation) {
                                case 0:
                                    break;

                                case 1:  
                                    System.out.println("Introduce the number you want to push");
                                    int num = sc.nextInt();
                                    stack.push(num);
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println("Pop: " + stack.pop());
                                    break;

                                default: 
                                    System.out.println("Error: Invalid answer, please try again");break;
                            }                       
                        }
                        break;                     
                    }  
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Hint: we can't actually reproduce your issue, because we don't know what you're inputting when you run it. You can replace your `main` method with a much simpler method that creates a `Stack`, pushes something in, pops something out, prints the value popped etc etc. Basically, remove the user input.

Comment: e.g. [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/XeWLyJ).

Comment: @GeorgeFrancis Delete all that code in `main` except for anything directly related to the problem.  The main loop and Stack, Queue, Exit menu?  Out! We're not dealing with Queues and exiting.  The stack menu?  Away with it, it obfuscates the problem and doesn't help.  The scanner?  Bye, use a few `int` variables and initialize them.  What'd be left is a `main` that's 10 lines of code max.  It'd push a couple, pop&print some, push one, pop&print all values, see if that all works...

Comment: Every time you loop around you create a new stack.

Comment: Thank you! This finally solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what happens when your stack is empty (i.e. `top == 0`): because you are using the pre-incremented value of `top`, you currently store the value into element 1, not element 0.

Use `top++` instead, so that the value is put into element 0 instead, before advancing `top` to 1.

---

Similarly, when popping, if you have one element in the stack (`top == 1`), you need to return element 0. So, use `--top` instead.

Comment: Agh, I see I mixed the 2 of them up, however now I get an ArrayOutOfBounds exception at the pop() method in my stack class and in the main when I call that method.
.
.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at stacksandqueues.Stack.pop(Stack.java:27)
 at stacksandqueues.StacksAndQueues.main(StacksAndQueues.java:38)

Comment: Then you're calling `pop` before `push` (or, more generally, calling `pop` more times than you call `push`)

Comment: But how could that happen?
I'm sure I first try to push a number into the array and then remove it with pop.
I'm not sure if it's relevant but if remove the break;  line at the end of case: 1, then the program actually doesn remove the number I just entered, but why doesn't this happen with the break; line in place?

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing   the index of top before inserting data at the top of `stack`.
And you are decrementing the index of top after popping data from `stack`.

So the code should be like this ....

```
public void push(int a) {
  stack[top++] = a;
 }
public int pop() {
  return stack[--top];
 }
```

Try to take an example and visualize the whole process on paper.Then it will be easily clear to you.

Comment: Yes, I see I got the two of them mixed up, but regardless even after fixing that I now receive an ArrayOutOfBounds exception when trying to use the pop(); method, even if I have placed numbers inside the array.